# Аутентификация на сервисе без API в request python

Tags: python, http, request, auth

Хочу сделать парсер форума, однако нужная мне информация (ссылки) на этом форуме скрыта для незарегистрированных пользователей.

```
self.headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0'}
self.forumUrl : str = "https://3board.ksivi.bz"
data_dict = {'login' : 'login', 'password' : 'password'}
response = self.session.post(self.forumUrl + '/login/login', data  = data_dict)
print(responce)
```

Выдает ошибку 400, то есть неправильно составленный запрос. Я подозреваю, что дело в названии полей login и password, потому что в каждом примере на эту тему они называются по-своему. Как узнать, как назвать их правильно?

Comment: Навскидку - открываешь иходный код страницы и смотришь, как называются поля у формы, которая отвечает за ввод логина/пароля, либо лучше - "инструменты разработчика" в браузере, вкладка "network", где можно посмотреть все взаимодействия с сервером.

Comment: еще может быть CSRF токен, его нужно парсить со страницы перед входом. а может и не быть.